# C# SQL Database Not Inserting Data

Tags: c#, sql

I have an SQL database with a relative file path specified. I know that the file path works because the program runs without errors. However, my SQL worked fine until I changed my file path from a full path to this relative path.

When I press the submit button on my WFA, the program looks as if it is saving to the database as there is a brief pause, but when I look within my `Student` table, no data has been inserted. Again, there are no errors.

I added a break point at the `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FullName", sFnameTxtBox.Text);` and it does not appear in the locals tab.

In the data sources tab, there is sometimes a red x icon by `SRSDB.mdf`, however when I refresh it the red x icon disappears.

When the user enters their details into the text boxes, the details should be inserted into the `student` table upon pressing submit.

```
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient; 
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
       SqlCommand command; 
        SqlConnection connection;
        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter; 

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

          connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="+ Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "SRSDB.mdf"));

          connection.Open();

          command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Student (FullName, Email, TelNo,     Username, Password) VALUES (@FullName, @Email, @TelNo, @Username, @Password)", connection);

          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FullName", sFnameTxtBox.Text);

          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", sEmailTxtBox.Text);

          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TelNo", sTelNoTxtBox.Text);

          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", sUnameTxtBox.Text);

          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", sPwordTxtBox.Text);

          command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where @FullName parameter passing value

Comment: There is no `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FullName", sFnameTxtBox.Text);` line in your code.

Comment: How exactly did you add a break point to a line of code that doesn't exist?  When you try to execute this query, you *will* get an error.  Examine that error, it's telling you the problem.  Also, side note, ***never store user passwords in plain text***.  That is ***grossly irresponsible*** to your users.

Comment: Sorry, it does exist. I forgot to copy and paste the line in: command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FullName", sFnameTxtBox.Text);

Answer (score 0):

I would infer that for some reason you are writing to a different location than you think.

To confirm this, run a query against the database in your code, and see if the data which you just inserted is returned. If it is, then the write to the database has been successful: but you are writing to an MDF file which isn't visible to you in your project.

I'd pull out the path construction into a local variable:

```
string dbPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "SRSDB.mdf");
connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=" + dbPath);
```

put your breakpoint on that, get the value of `dbPath`, and see what's there. Is that the MDF file which you are expecting?

It is also good practice to hold your connection string in a single location. If you ever have cause to change it, then a single change fixes your whole app. So declare it somewhere once, and then just access it from there every time.

Comment: I tried what you suggested Hamish, but it is giving me a syntax error, saying ',' expected on the second line @ dbpath and also: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCredential'

Comment: I omitted the "+". My fault for not running the code to check it first.

I have now run the code. The path looks valid, but it is in the root folder. Where is your MDF which is visible in your project? You can check by looking under "Server Explorer", clicking on the database, and checking the properties (right-click/Properties). The connection string which you are building in code needs to match the connection string of the database you can see in you project.

Comment: I added the break point and it is pointing to the bin\debug folder, I have my database saved there as it saves in the debug folder automatically, and I have it saved at the directory before bin. If I overwrite database in bin\debug, it returns file not found, otherwise it returns no error.

Comment: And where is the database that you can see in your project in Visual Studio? The one which does NOT have the row inserted? Did you also try to read the record back using code, to make sure it had saved (given that you didn't get an error)?

Comment: The path for the database as specified by the solution explorer is: F:\Uni\ADD\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1. It seems when I moved the database to the bin\debug folder, the solution explorer is still pointing to the database being in F:\Uni\ADD\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1 when actually the database is located: F:\Uni\ADD\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\debug. When I try to run the program & the db is in bin\debug, file not found error occurs.

Comment: Otherwise, when saved in just F:\Uni\ADD\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1 it will run and display no error, but no data is being passed to the database, if data was being passed, it would have showed when I added the break point.

Comment: It sounds as if the data was being written to the bin\debug DB, but you were looking at the solution DB.

I would advise:

1) Change the solution DB to point to your bin\debug DB and check that after the insert

2) As I advised before - do a SELECT in the code immediately after the INSERT, and see if you get the correct data back.

The only other reason I can think of the data not being returned is if you had an unclosed transaction - which you don't.

Comment: But a better fix altogether would be to have a connection string somewhere global. Always use that connection string to access your DB. Make sure that connection string is the same as your solution DB.

No matter if you run debug or release, you'll hit the correct database. If you ever move the DB, you have *one* connection string to update, and *everything* that uses it will still hit the correct DB.

You should have the connection string in a configuration file somewhere (where exactly is up to you). Then, when you deploy, an administrator can change the DB location without having to recode.